# Use apply_along_axis to plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have a 3D ndarry object, which contains spectral data (i.e. spatial xy dimensions, and an energy dimension). I would like to extract and plot the spectra from each individual pixel in a line plot.  At present, I am doing this using np.ndenumerate along the axis I'm interested in, but it's quite slow.  I was hoping to try `np.apply_along_axis`, to see if it was faster, but I keep getting a strange error.

What works:

```
# Setup environment, and generate sample data (much smaller than real thing!)
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = range(0,10) # the scale to use when plotting the axis of interest
ar = np.random.rand(4,4,10) # the 3D data volume

# Plot all lines along axis 2 (i.e. the spectrum contained in each pixel) 
# on a single line plot:

for (x,y) in np.ndenumerate(ar[:,:,1]):
    plt.plot(ax,ar[x[0],x[1],:],alpha=0.5,color='black')
```

It is my understanding that this is basically a loop, which is less efficient than array-based methods, so I would like to try an approach using `np.apply_along_axis`, to see if it's faster.  This is my first attempt at python, however, and am still finding out how it works, so please put me right if this idea is fundamentally flawed!

What I would like to try:

```
# define a function to pass to apply_along_axis
def pa(y,x):
    if ~all(np.isnan(y)): # only do the plot if there is actually data there...
        plt.plot(x,y,alpha=0.15,color='black')
    return

# check that the function actually works...
pa(ar[1,1,:],ax) # should produce a plot - does for me :)

# try to apply to to the whole array, along the axis of interest:
np.apply_along_axis(pa,2,ar,ax) # does not work... booo!
```

The resulting error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-5192831ba03c> in <module>()
     12 # pa(ar[1,1,:],ax)
     13 
---> 14 np.apply_along_axis(pa,2,ar,ax)

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.pyc in apply_along_axis(func1d, axis, arr, *args)
    101         holdshape = outshape
    102         outshape = list(arr.shape)
--> 103         outshape[axis] = len(res)
    104         outarr = zeros(outshape, asarray(res).dtype)
    105         outarr[tuple(i.tolist())] = res

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Any ideas whats going wrong here/advice on how to do this better would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply_along_axis` creates *a new array* from the output of your function.

You're returning `None` (by not returning anything). Thus the error. Numpy checks the length of the returned output to see if it makes sense for the new array.

Because you're not constructing a new array from the results, there's no reason to use `apply_along_axis`. It's not going to be any faster.

However, your current `ndenumerate` statement is exactly equivalent to:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ar = np.random.rand(4,4,10) # the 3D data volume
plt.plot(ar.reshape(-1, 10).T, alpha=0.5, color='black')
```

In general, you probably want to do something like:

```
for pixel in ar.reshape(-1, ar.shape[-1]):
    plt.plot(x_values, pixel, ...)
```

That way you can easily iterate over the spectra at each pixel in your hyperspectral array.

---

You bottleneck here probably isn't how you're using the array. Plotting each line separately with identical parameters like this in `matplotlib` is going to be somewhat inefficient.

It will take slightly longer to construct, but a `LineCollection` will render much faster. (Basically, using a `LineCollection` tells matplotlib to not bother checking what the properties of each line are, and just pass them all to the low-level renderer to be drawn in the same way. You bypass a bunch of individual `draw` calls in favor of a single `draw` of a large object.)

On the downside, the code will be a bit less readable.

I'll add an example in a bit.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!  The LineCollection sounds a lot more like what I'm after - if you can manage an example, I'd really appreciate it.